# awsのpolicyの作り方を教えてください

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-11",
  "Id": "Policy1503119012324",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "Stmt15031190096534",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
    "Condition": {
      ここで特定のIAMユーザーを例外にしたい
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NotPrincipal` を使って IAMユーザの ARN を指定すれば良いと思います。
ARNは`"arn:aws:iam::AWSアカウントID:user/IAMユーザ名"` という形式です。

```
{
  "Id": "Policys3IamUserAccessControl",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "mybucket01",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket" ],
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/take88" <- 例外IAMユーザ
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```